# Add the ability to hide multiple communities at once

Tags: feature-request, hidden-communities

Given that there are (currently) 176 sites on Stack Exchange, and because sites that I don't participate in have been showing up in my Communities list like Blender, I would like to have the ability to hide multiple communities at once, e.g.

[image]

You can add multiple tags at once to your [tag watching/ignoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current), so this would make it consistent as well.

Comment: This is *one* time when I would find the [multiple] tag useful, @Glorfindel ;)  Not that I want it, of course.

Answer (score 8):

This is in fact awkward, but I think a better solution would be, instead of having a search box that requires you to already know which community you want to hide to simply show all visible communities and allow them to be selected from the convenient list that already exists and allows multiple communities to be easily hidden by clicking the "hide" button on each.  It also means you don't have to flip between your profile and the "Hide Communities" page to tell which communities are visible.

In terms of space taken up, it already displays every hidden community (I have 85 hidden, and there's no truncation).  This page is also only viewed on the rare occasion that you want to edit which communities are hidden, so keeping it uncluttered should not be especially important.